# Javascript getMonth() and getDate transions issuse

Tags: javascript

Hello i am trying to write the following function to display 7 days of the week

```
function displaydates(){
// read the string output from the datepicker and
    //evalutes which date goes  into which cell

var date = document.getElementById("datepicker"); // Mon APR 30 2012 HH:MM:SS

var m = new Date(date.value);
var num = parseInt(m.getDate());
    var i = 0;
    var days=[];
    var x;
    for(i; i<=6; i++){
        var day= m.setDate(num+i);
        var month = m.setMonth(m.getMonth());
        x = m.getMonth()+1 + "/" + m.getDate() + "<br />";
        days.push(x);
    }
       document.getElementById("Monday").innerHTML= days[0];
       document.getElementById("Tuesday").innerHTML=days[1];
       document.getElementById("Wednesday").innerHTML=days[2];
       document.getElementById("Thursday").innerHTML=days[3];
       document.getElementById("Friday").innerHTML=days[4];
       document.getElementById("Saturday").innerHTML=days[5];
       document.getElementById("Sunday").innerHTML=days[6];
}
```

the code works fine as long as it's seven days before the next month.the problem i am having is when the user wants to see the next seven day the function outputs the wrong information
for example

```
var m = new Date("Apr 30 2012"); / /monday
```

will make my function out put the following

4/29, 5/30, 7/1, 9/1, 11/2, 1/3, 3/7

again, this only happens on transition to the next month is there and thing i can do to make the month to month transition work in my function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call, for example, `setDate(32)`, JavaScript figures out that that requires an additional month and adds it to the date. When you later call `setDate(33)`, it once again adds an extra month...

This solution might work better (some parts are omitted):

```
var start = new Date();
var days = [];
for(var i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
    var str = (start.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + start.getDate() + '<br />';
    days.push(str);
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much I've been stuck on this problem longer than i can to be and not seeing this code it's all so very clear to me :p again thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below provided solution

```
function displaydates(){
// read the string output from the datepicker and
    //evalutes which date goes  into which cell

var date = document.getElementById("datepicker"); // Mon APR 30 2012 HH:MM:SS

var m = new Date(date.value);
var num = m.getTime();
    var i = 0;
    var days=[];
    var x;
    for(i; i<=6; i++){
        num+=86400000;    //Edited Part
        m = new Date(num);
        var day= m.getDate();
        var month = m.getMonth();
        x = month+1 + "/" + day + "<br />";
        days.push(x);
    }
       document.getElementById("Monday").innerHTML= days[0];
       document.getElementById("Tuesday").innerHTML=days[1];
       document.getElementById("Wednesday").innerHTML=days[2];
       document.getElementById("Thursday").innerHTML=days[3];
       document.getElementById("Friday").innerHTML=days[4];
       document.getElementById("Saturday").innerHTML=days[5];
       document.getElementById("Sunday").innerHTML=days[6];
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks for the help but this creates a new problem for me. it only print the same day 7 times there is no day increase with each iteration

Comment: Hey I have changed the answer, now you use this function you'll get the correct answer

Comment: This will trip over Daylight Savings.